# Change logo in a beamer template

Tags: beamer, templates

I'm working with this beamer template: https://www.overleaf.com/10300591bjdrrvvnhwhd#/38204546/

I would like to change the university logo and name in the top left corner but I can't find an option to achieve this goal. The only options in `phil-pdflatex.tex` are these:

```
%% These macros specify information about the presentation
\title{Presentation Title} %% that will be typeset on the
\subtitle{Presentation Subtitle} %% title page.
\author{Author's Name}
```

Moreover, there is a logo folder in `/fibeamer/logo/mu` that contains two pdf files completely blank.

How can I change the university logo and name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is part of the image and `fibeamer-mu-phil-english.pdf` is not completly blank, it's the white logo with a transparent background. If viewed on top of a coloured area, you will see:

[image]

So to change the logo and the name, replace the `.pdf` file or specify your own image via

```
\usetheme[logo=example-image]{fibeamer}
```